# Prove that there exists n such that $\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\frac{x}{y}<\frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\frac{x}{y}<\frac{1}{n}$ where $\frac{x}{y}$ is a rational number and $0<\frac{x}{y}<1$ and $x,y>0$ and $x$ and $y$ have no common divisors.

Comment: @abiessu, I worked backwards and I can get to the final answer if $x[(n+1)-n]\geq1$. From this, $x(n+1)\geq xn+1$ so $x(n+1)$ and $xn$ are more than (or equal to 1 apart). Thus, there must be a positive integer $y$ between them. Rearranging gives the desired result. But I don't know how to bridge the gap at the beginning. Also, I just realised as I am typing that I assumed that $x$ and $y$ are integers. Can I do that?

Comment: If $\frac xy$ is rational, then there exist integers $w,z$ such that $\frac wz = \frac xy$.  I think you can safely assume each of $x,y$ is an integer.

Comment: @abiessu So if $x>0$ and an integer, then $x\geq1$ and then $x[n+1-n]\geq1$ and then my first comment. Is this all I need to do?

Comment: I would still be interested in your method using $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ too. I know its positive but I don't see how it is useful... Thanks for your help by the way :)

Comment: I have discovered that my difference of fractions comment doesn't really help in any direct way, only in a semi-persuasive way.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Consider $\lfloor\dfrac{y}{x}\rfloor$. Also note that this is *not* the answer.

Comment: $\lfloor \frac{y}{x} \rfloor >1$ I'm not sure how else to use this?

Comment: $\dfrac{y}{x}$ is greater that $1$, not its integer part. Your inequality is equivalent to $n<\dfrac{y}{x}\le n+1$. If you take $n$ equal to the expression in my hint then it will satisfy this inequality iff $\dfrac{y}{x}$ is not itself a natural number. How can you change it to include this case too?

Comment: $\frac{y}{x}$ is a natural number only when $x=1$. Then let $\lfloor \frac{y}{x} \rfloor =n+1$?

Comment: Yes, you can say in that way too. So you have the solution of the problem. But it is also possible to construct one formula for all cases, I meant that formula.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have all the pieces, so here's how I would approach the problem:

Given rational $\frac xy$ such that $0\lt \frac xy \lt 1$, we have $0\lt x \lt y$, or $1 \lt \frac yx$.  There must exist a positive integer $n$ such that $n\le \frac yx\le n+1$, which means that $\frac 1n\ge \frac xy\ge \frac 1{n+1}$.

Given that $\frac 1n \gt \frac 1{n+1}$, we can say that if $\frac xy=\frac 1k$, choose $n=k-1$ so we can write $\frac 1n\gt \frac xy \ge \frac 1{n+1}$.  Then we have shown the required inequality.

Alternatively, note that $\frac 1n - \frac 1{n+1}=\frac 1{n(n+1)}$, meaning that there is a nonempty interval of values between the two.  Further, note that for all $n$, if $\frac xy \lt \frac 1{n+1}$, then let $n\to n+1$ and compare again.